# Continuity and show one limit is equal to the value of a function

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck on this:

Suppse that $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f(x^n) dx = f(0)$. I know that if $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ it is Riemann integrable. And I was thinking about using composition of functions to show that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}, f(x^n)$ was Riemann Integrable.

Is this on the right track?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f(x^n)$=$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1-t} f(x^n)$+$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{1-t}^{1} f(x^n)$ Use the fact that $x^{n}$  is uniformly convergent on $0 \le x<1$,hence first integral gives $(1-t)f(0)$.For second integral use continuity and finally setting $t$ tends to zero gives the result.